# Как заполнять input text по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, есть код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('li').click(function(){

      var qwe = $(this).text();
      $('input').val(qwe);
  });
});
```

По клику на дивы, в *input* должны помещаться содержимое дивов.
На данный момент значения заменяются, а мне нужно чтобы добавлялись.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно вас понял, то нужно просто взять уже имеющееся значение и добавить к нему вновь введённое.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('li').click(function(){
      var text = $('input').text();
      var qwe = $(this).text();
      $('input').val(text + qwe);
      });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но ваш код работает аналогично моему. то есть затирает в inpute предыдущее значение и вставляет новое. а мне нужно что бы как на калькуляторе. нажимаем кнопочки а из цифр формируется число.:)))

Comment: спасибо за помощь. вот так работает
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('li').click(function(){ 
        var text = $('input').val();
        var qwe = $(this).text();
    $('input').val(text + qwe);
    
    });
    
    });

Comment: Тогда пометьте ответ галочкой

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#wrap > div').bind('click', function() {
  var val = $('#input').val();
  var num = $(this).text()
  $('#input').val(val + num)
});
```

```css
#wrap>div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2px;
}

#wrap>div:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input" value="123" type="text">
<div id="wrap">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</div>
```

Логика проста: При нажатии на *div* запоминаем значение *input*, узнаём значение *div*, вставляем в *input* оба значения по очереди.